# Android: ListView Selector set to null?

Tags: android, css-selectors, android-listview

I want to disable the [`Selector`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android%3alistSelector) from my `ListView`. That's when I click any items there will be no indication that it has been clicked.

I tried this in my ListView tag:
`android:listSelector="@null"` and didn't work

Comment: do u mean u want to remove orange color effect when clicking listview item ???

Comment: Yes. It differs from one phone to another. But it is orange in some cases.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

set this android:listSelector="#00000000" Try this.

Comment: Why not use @android:color/transparent instead #00000000?

Answer (score 6):

The above answer from Kalpana is correct. You can also do it in code like this:-

```
myListView.setSelector(new ColorDrawable(0x0));
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a new drawable to use as selector, that wouldn't have any state in it :

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@android:color/background_dark" />
</selector>
```

and then set it using the android:listSelector attribute. You can reference one of the android colors as the background color in your selector : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.color.html

Answer (score 0):

```
mListView.setSelector(new StateListDrawable());
```