# click in each item on Listview

Tags: android, listview, android-imageview

I have a problem because I'm developing an Android application and each row of my listview contains this:

```
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:stretchColumns="1">

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:visibility="gone"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:background="@drawable/border"/>

</TableRow>

<TableRow
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="1.2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:padding="10dip"
        android:layout_margin="4dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.7"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="12dp"/>

</TableRow>
```

All listview is shown correctly, but when I click in the photo or in the first item I can't select the photo or the first item separately. This screenshot show it:[image]

If I click on the first item the photo is selected too and if I click on the photo the first item is selected. With the header I have the same problem.

The structure of each listview row is the following:

```
<Header>
<Photo>
<Rows (can be more than 1)> -->This works fine
```

With I have more than one row below the photo with second and following there are no problem. The problem is with first row and photo, that when I click on one of this it is selected the header, photo and the first row.

How can I solve this problem, because the photo is hidden by the header and the first row too how can be seen in the screenshot.

Thanks!!

Edited:

I have a bitmap to show in imageview. The problem is in the imageview does not show the full photo, because the photo is cutted up and down (just where header and first row). Somebody knows the problem showing bitmaps in listview. The black borders should be in up and down side in the photo, but this are hidden by the header and first row.

I used a tablelayout because my structure is the following:

```
<TableLayout> 
   <TableRow> //User detail with three columns for image forename and surname
   <TableRow> //For image (1 column)
   <TableRow> //For many rows, to load with descriptions or comments (4 columns)
```

Comment: You're saying that you're not able to click on any individual items or just that they gain focus when any one is clicked?

Comment: I don't have any alert dialog, therefore I don't know, but in listview I put this `android:listSelector="@null"` and when I click in an individual item header, photo and first row is selected in orange how appears in the screenshot. This only happens with photo and first item in the table, the others items work fine.

Comment: Try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6633374/android-listview-selector-set-to-null)

Comment: But with this I only obtain that the area coloured will be transparent. The result is the same. My proble is that the imageview is over header and first row but on back, therefore the header and row is visible.

Comment: I'm not sure whether I understand your doubt. Could you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: Sorry if I cannot explain me fine. I have a listview with three main item in each row (header, photo and table). Header and table are over the photo, therefore the photo appears cut by there. I think that the problem is the same that when I click on the photo and header and first row are selected. I think I have a problem with layout but I've tried some changes (Tables, Linear, Relative) and nothing works. The code above is for each row in ListView

Comment: I update the end of my post for if anybody knows the answer

Comment: You have 2 images here. Which one are you saying is clipped?

Comment: All pictures are behind the header and first row, so when you select any of these three items all that is selected.

Comment: I'll try and redesign your row in a different way. I don't see why a table layout is used here.

Comment: I update my post. At the end I posted why TableLayout, because I think is the best way, but if you have a better idea it is great for me. I can change my code to works fine. Thanks

Comment: I found the problem. I have header, imageview and some rows. When I touch one of these elements in listview the first item contains all of this. But in other rows header and imageview have the atribute GONE. Therefore should be able to inflate two xml in the same listview? I don't know how I can do this

Comment: You want different XML for first row and other rows in the listview?

Comment: If that is your doubt, then yes it is possible.

Comment: Yes I want split each block in listview in three differents blocks (Header, photo and table), by this way I could touch each item separately, because now when I touch the listview I touch all the items. Each block is the xml file that I inflate from xml. How can I inflate three xml from my listview?

Comment: You need to check and set according to child type. Check **[this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12286235/using-two-different-layouts-for-child-items-in-expandablelistview)** example. In the answer, the code checks for 2 types. You can check for 3.